# Website displays on desktop browser and Android devices but not iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, web

My [website](https://opsonion.com/) displays perfectly fine on my desktop browser, Android devices but not on any iOS devices. I just get a white screen. Any idea on how to fix it?

- [Screenshot on Android device](https://preview.redd.it/dtxgbqg5yxy41.png?width=899&format=png&auto=webp&s=ef7b9ef0cde272c4142f12f757ae76fc60097054)
- [Screenshot on iOS device](https://preview.redd.it/becm5luyxxy41.png?width=900&format=png&auto=webp&s=cfbd54e81c778a5e350bfe754a22705d83d552e5)

I might have a JavaScript call that's not working in iOS. It could be a 3rd party polyfill that is failing and causing some other issues as well. I don't know any better method for debugging iOS.

Comment: You should target *browsers*, not devices. There is no such thing as a "desktop browser" and "android device" is not a browser either. You are probably using Regex features that are not yet implemented in all browsers (namely Firefox and Safari). Start by using these browsers' developer tools to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, turned out to be regex related!